# OSMDroid: Adding a marker when user taps on map

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to display a marker on map where user taps on map. 
Also this should not infect double tap for zooming and/or moving **`Mapview`**.

I am using osmdroid-android-4.0.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at OSMBonusPack MapEventsOverlay/MapEventsReceiver:

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/MapEventsOverlay.java

You create a MapEventsOverlay, you add it to the maps overlay, and you pass it a MapEventsReceiver in which you implement your own singleTapUpHelper code.