# How to handle long press on a map, using OSMDroid / OSMBonusPack in Android?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am trying to create a simple application with maps, on Android. I am using OSMDroid's `MapView` to render the basic OpenStreet Map mapview.

I have a custom `MapActivity` that implements the `MapEventsReceiver` interface (from OSMBonusPack). In my activity's `onCreate()`, I create a `MapEventsOverlay`, I add it to the `mapView`.

The problem is, `longPressHelper()` and `singleTapUpHelper()` are never called. See my code below.

```
public abstract class CustomMap extends BaseActivity implements MapEventsReceiver{
//variable declarations follow
private MapView mMapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(load);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_main_screen);

mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapmainscreen);
mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mMapView.setClickable(true);

MapEventsOverlay evOverlay = new MapEventsOverlay(this, this);
mMapView.getOverlays.add(evOverlay);
mMapView.invalidate();

//tile source / tile provider are set by another method elsewhere

//somewhere in my code (same class file) I also have this:

@Override
public boolean longPressHelper(IGeoPoint arg0) {
Log.d(TAG, "longPressHelper was called");//this is never called
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean singleTapUpHelper(IGeoPoint arg0) {
Log.d(TAG, "singleTapUpHelper was called");//this is never called
return true;
}
}      
}
```

Please note that I have tried the suggested solution here [OSMDroid: Adding a marker when user taps on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946715/osmdroid-adding-a-marker-when-user-taps-on-map)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is correct. 
So the issue is somewhere else...

Could you specify versions used: Android SDK, osmdroid, and OSMBonusPack?

Maybe something in the layout? You can check by comparing with OSMBonusPackTuto activity_main.xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Code needs changing now (API 26?), older methods deprecated.
Something like this:

```
    MapEventsReceiver mReceive = new MapEventsReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p)
        {
            //do whatever you need here
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p)
        {
            //do whatever you need here
            return false;
        }
    };
    MapEventsOverlay evOverlay = new MapEventsOverlay(mReceive);
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(evOverlay);
```